# The right way to import images to html using Webpack

Tags: javascript, image, webpack, minify

I'm using [React + Redux-saga + Auth0](https://github.com/jch254/starter-pack) package, and it's using *Webpack*. Usually I work with Gulp, and I started just lately using Webpack so I don't have much experience with it.

Let's say I have the image `Project/src/static/images/hello.jpg` and I want to use it on my app like this:

```
<img src="images/hello.jpg" alt=".." />
```

- How do I tell webpack to compile that folder into the `dist` folder?
- I've noticed that the images I imported from my `.scss` files have a compiled with a hashed name. So even if I compile my images, how would I get its full path?
- I tried to google this issue and I haven't found any issues like this one, so I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong, am I?

This is my [webpack.config.babel.js](https://jsfiddle.net/qt1dkod2/) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously I'm using expressjs server which has the option to [Serve static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). So what I did is just adding this line of code in my `devServer.js` file:

```
app.use(express.static('src/static'));
```